# Getting content of LINKMAP properties in a Java HashMap

Tags: java, orientdb

I'm trying to work with LINKMAP properties.

Let's say we have Vertex PokemonMaster as follow

```
PokemonMaster
{
 name, (STRING)
 age, (INTEGER)
 pokemons, (LINKMAP) of Pokemon
}
```

Containing a LINKMAP of Pokemon

```
Pokemon
{
  name, (STRING)
}
```

The following code is working to create a PokemonMaster giving him some Pokemon :

```
Map<String, ODocument> pokemons = new HashMap<>();
ODocument pikachu = new ODocument("Pokemon");
pikachu.field("name", "Pikachu");
pikachu.save();
ODocument raichu = new ODocument("Pokemon");
raichu.field("name", "Raichu");
raichu.save();
pokemons.put("pikachu", pikachu);
pokemons.put("raichu", raichu);
graph.addVertex("class:PokemonMaster", "name", "Sacha", "age", "42", "pokemons", pokemons);
```

Now what we've got in the DB is something like :

```
{"pikachu":"#15:42","raichu":"#15:43"}
```

for Sacha, #15:42 and #15:43 being the rids of pikachu and raichu.

Here is my problem :
I can't get this Map into a Java HashMap.

What I mean is, i would like to be able to do something like :

```
Vertex v = graph.getVertex(id); // getting the instance of Sacha
Map<String, ODocument> map = v.getProperty("pokemons");
System.out.println(map.get("pikachu").getIdentity());
System.out.println(map.get("raichu").getIdentity());
```

This was my first try, then i thought this would not make sense to get an ODocument as value since it's an id which is store in the table.
So I tried :

```
Vertex v = graph.getVertex(id); // getting the instance of Sacha
Map<String, String> map = v.getProperty("pokemons");
```

Hoping to get the id in the value.
But nothing is working, saying the following error :

```
com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientElementIterable cannot be cast to java.util.Map
```

So I tried OrientElementIterable as follow :

```
Vertex v = graph.getVertex(id); // getting the instance of Sacha
OrientElementIterable<Element> test = v.getProperty("pokemons");
for (Element elem : test) {
 System.out.println(elem.getProperty("name"));
}
```

And it actually worked, printing me "Raichu" and "Pikachu". But this is transforming my Map into a simple list, and I'm losing the key/value feature.

My question is, is there a way to get the LINKMAP properties into a Java Map?

I know this is working with EMBEDDEDMAP, but i'd like it to work with LINKMAP

**EDIT : FIRST SOLUTION**

I found a first solution for those who need

It's possible to change the Vertex into a ODocument like :

```
ODocument doc = new ODocument(new ORecordId(v.getId().toString()));
```

And then we can get the map easily :

```
Map<String, ORecordId> map = doc.field("pokemons");
```

And then the key contains the name of the pokemon and the value represents the id of his instance.

Comment: Thanks! In a similar manner it can be used this solution for LinkList and other link types.